# Grass variety in hot climate

Tags: grass

I m facing a huge problem with my grass growing. In living in a country which has hot climate for almost 7 months per year and the grass does not grow up at all. The seeds are destroyed. Do you have any grass variety to propose?

- Temperature: 95-105 for almost 6 months (end of April to September)
- Location: Cyprus
- Humidity: rarely, in normal levels
- Rain: in winter but in normal level

Comment: You should give more details on where do you live, or temperature (and humidity, and rain) range. I'm sure that "hot climate" mean different temperatures by different people in this site.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi please see updates in the question

Comment: Last question: are you near the sea? So salty soil?

Comment: There is no sea, but i m not sure about salty soil.

Comment: Do you want this grass to form a mowed or short cut lawn or do you want the grass to remain long / tall as a decorative plant?

Answer (score 1):

[This University of Arkansas discussion](https://www.uaex.edu/yard-garden/resource-library/plant-week/cynodon-dactylon-bermudagrass-06-24-2016.aspx) speaks about how Crabgrass (the tropical type) Cynodon dactylon is extremely tough and is much used in very hot dry environments. However note that it needs to be treated rough and kept under control, otherwise it can get out of hand. It is perennial, spreads underground, and roots very deeply which enables it to survive very hot dry conditions. It pretty much always looks rough but that is the price you pay for something green and flat in the tropical zone.

Answer (score 1):

St Augustine , it is not seeded but sodded or plugged . Plugs a foot apart will fill in during one season. But, it does need water.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost ideal conditions for Bermuda grass, which is sold as seed.

It is fast growing, hard wearing (commonly used for sports turf in the southern USA), and drought tolerant.

Comment: I live in Phoenix, AZ and Bermuda grass is the "summer" grass of choice. Rye grass is planted as "winter" grass. It can't stand the heat, and Bermuda grass can't stand the cold, so it works out. Both need irrigation if there is not enough natural moisture.